# Central administration on sharepoint 2010 runs slowly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a peculiar problems with the Sharepoint 2010. It takes a very long time to start the Central Administration for the first time. Navigation through CA is then rather okay, but when I try to create a web application it takes about 5 minutes before I can see the first configuration window. Initialization of Sharepoint Management Shell takes a lot of time, similar amount 2-3 minutes.

It's a Windows 2008 and is running on the VirtualBox VM with good hardware parameters, about 20 gb of RAM, quite efficient processor, however CPU & memory utilizations are low.  Other applications run fine, only the Sharepoint causes a problems.

Domain controller for mentioned machine also runs on VirualBox and also has low utilization of CPU and usage of RAM.

Both of the machines doesn't have the Internet access.

EDIT:
It seems the problem was in spoiled virtual machine instance, however on the new instance efficiency has improved after the installation of the Sharepoint tools from the VisualStudio 2010 and it's SP1. Anyway I wouldn't be perfectly sure about given explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to add app **pool account** to **local group IIS_WPG**.

Comment: Don't you mean WSS_WPG?

Comment: No. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tehnoonr/archive/2012/05/17/sharepoint-central-administration-web-site-takes-a-long-time-to-load-after-an-iis-reset.aspx

Comment: Wow it's this! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`SQL > properties > Memory > Minimum Server Memory`, change it from 0 to 5 GB if it is not set.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I increased the value of minimum SQL server memory but it didn't help.

Altough I found quite popular problem with the Security Token Service within logs: 
"An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9160156. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.."

Currently I'm tinkering with the issue.

Comment: @Landeeyo that why we love sharepoint. My answere is most common thing that we do in case of "slow sharepoint" but I will remeber your comment. Ofc remeber that mc support will help you if u have good license